# Change background color of cell based on sql table number

Tags: php, html, mysql

First question here on stack, also very new to php as you can probably tell from my code below. What im trying to do is populate information from a database onto a page. It appears in table format and users can search for specific records by one or more filters. What id like to do is have the 'age' filter show the record with a different color background depending on the age. It will work for one, as in it will show all users whose ages are less than 22 with an orange background. What id like it to do (and I think this is the part where I just dont understand the syntax yet) is to display all records whose ages are less than 19 with a Red background AND all records whose ages are less than 22 with an Orange background.

What im trying to say in the code below is if the row record for 'age' is less than 22, give the table row a background color of ffab0a, if its less than 19 give the table row a background color of ffff99, anything else, no background color.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction? below is the part that controls this thanks!

```
if ($row["age"]<22)
   echo '<tr style="background-color:#ffab0a">';
else if ($row["age"]<19)
   echo '<tr style="background-color:#ffff99">';
else
   echo '<tr>'; ?> 

<td><?php echo $row["age"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["location"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["form"]; ?></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that you're working in the wrong order. You have to check first, if the person is under 19 and then, if he/she is under 22. Otherwise somebody age 18 will also be colored orange, because of course 18 is smaller than 22.

```
<?
if ($row["age"]<19)
   echo '<tr style="background-color:#ffff99">';
else if ($row["age"]<22)
   echo '<tr style="background-color:#ffab0a">';
else
   echo '<tr>'; 
?> 

<td><?php echo $row["age"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["location"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["form"]; ?></td>
```

Comment: thanks so much, did exactly what I needed it to. Appreciate you taking the time to answer my question!

Answer (score 0):

Create a function which converts an age to a color.

```
<?php
    function age_style($age) {
        if ($age < 19) return 'background-color:#ffff99';
        if ($age < 22) return 'background-color:#ffab0a';
        return '';
    }
?>
```

Then your table rendering can be a bit cleaner:

```
<tr style="<?=age_style($row['age'])?>">
    <td><?= $row["age"]; ?></td>
    <td><?= $row["location"]; ?></td>
    <td><?= $row["form"]; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Doesn't that look nicer? It gives you a single location to easily update the styles when you need to in the future.

Comment: ill try this on another build, thank you for taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it slightly differently...

```
<?php
if ($row['age'] < 22) { $style = 'background-color: #ffab0a'; }
if ($row['age'] < 19) { $style = 'background-color: #ffff99'; }
?>

<tr style="<?php echo $style; ?>">
<td><?php echo $row['age']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['location']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['form']; ?></td?
</tr>
```

This way, if you find that you need to make changes to the markup in the future, or if you wanted to add different conditions, you don't need to modify a bunch of `<tr>` tags.

Comment: ill try this on another build, thank you for taking the time to respond!